# Woocommerce's wc_get_orders not working in function.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get all orders from woocommerce. Following the instruction on https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

I put the following code in my function.php

```
// Get latest 3 orders.
$args = array(
    'limit' => 3,
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
var_dump($orders);
```

However, it outputs an empty array.
I checked my code and found I actually used `wc_get_orders` in a hook as below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'change_role_on_first_purchase',10,4 );
function change_role_on_first_purchase( $order_id,$old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
  $userID = $order->user_id;
  $user = new WP_User( $userID );
  if ( in_array('subscriber',$user->roles) ){
    $args = array(
      'customer' => $userID,
      'exclude' => array( $order->get_id() ),
      'status' => array('completed')
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);

    if (!$orders && $new_status == "completed"){
      $user->set_role('customer');
    }
  }
}
```

This is used to change the user's role from subscriber to customer after he places the first order. This function works on my site. So `wc_get_orders` works here. Why then it is not working in my function.php?

Comment: Typically the WC user role would be customer... right?

Comment: What does your functions.php look like? Is it a flat-file full of functions listed 1 by 1, or is there OOP functionality in there you need to work with?

Comment: @admcfajn are you suggesting that this function can not be put plainly in function.Php, instead it needs to be put in a hook?

Comment: You cant just run query from the air ....

Comment: Possibly, depending on how the functions.php file is structured, though it's unlikely. If it's just a regular functions.php with no namespace or oop structure it's probably fine. You might also want to tweak the priority `10,4` in your call to `add_action`

Answer (score 1):

It outputs an empty array because Woocommerce has not yet registered order types/statuses when you're calling `wc_get_orders()`

Try adding it after **init** event:

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_init' );

function test_init() {
     // Get latest 3 orders.
     $args = array(
         'limit' => 3,
     );
     $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
     var_dump($orders);
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/